# Inconsistent results with JSON.stringify in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to develop a dynamic menu for a site, where a user can click buttons to view the category of foods he has chosen, e.g. breakfast items, lunch items and milkshakes.

The code I'm using to make this happen is this:

<sub>Function filtering out the category of foods</sub>

```
function filterOut(item) {
  let stringifyThis = JSON.stringify(this);
  if (Object.values(item).includes(stringifyThis)) {
    populate(item)
  }
console.log(stringifyThis);
}
```

<sub>function assigning and detecting eventListeners for clicks (currenctly trying to understand the issue with "breakfast", thus the callback of a separate function instead of one-lining it like the rest</sub>

```
function clicked(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    switch(btn.dataset.id) {
      case 'all':
        menuItem.innerHTML = '';
        menu.map(populate);
        break;
      case 'breakfast':
        menuItem.innerHTML = '';
        menu.map(filterOut, 'breakfast');
        break;
      case 'lunch':
        menuItem.innerHTML = '';
        menu.map((i) => {
          if (Object.values(i).includes('lunch')) {
            populate(i)
          }
        });
        break;
      case 'shakes':
        menuItem.innerHTML = '';
        menu.map((i) => {
          if (Object.values(i).includes('shakes')) {
            populate(i)
          }
        });
        break;
      default:
        console.log('default');
        break;
    }
  });
}
```

<sub>a small sample of the array</sub>

```
const menu = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "buttermilk pancakes",
    category: "breakfast",
    price: 15.99,
    img: "./images/item-1.jpeg",
    desc: `I'm baby woke mlkshk wolf bitters live-edge blue bottle, hammock freegan copper mug whatever cold-pressed `,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "diner double",
    category: "lunch",
    price: 13.99,
    img: "./images/item-2.jpeg",
    desc: `vaporware iPhone mumblecore selvage raw denim slow-carb leggings gochujang helvetica man braid jianbing. Marfa thundercats `,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "godzilla milkshake",
    category: "shakes",
    price: 6.99,
    img: "./images/item-3.jpeg",
    desc: `ombucha chillwave fanny pack 3 wolf moon street art photo booth before they sold out organic viral.`,
  }
]
```

The expected result of the console.log would be 9 "breakfast" strings, where if I do `console.log(stringifyThis === 'breakfast')` , the browser would log out True, but instead, it logs out false.

When I `console.log(typeof Stringify)` it logs out "string"

Comment: Why are you calling `JSON.stringify()` on a string?

Comment: Get rid of that call. It's adding literal `"` characters around the string, which don't match the values in the object.

Comment: `if (Object.values(item).includes(stringifyThis)) {` Why? If you're always looking at the category property, it makes so much more sense to do `if (item.category === this) {`. Of course, it also makes more sense to just pass the value to be searched for to the function and make it `function filterOut(item, category) { if (item.category === category) { populate(item); } }`, but I digress...

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `JSON.stringify(this)`. When `this` is a string, this will convert it to JSON, which adds `"` characters around it. The values in the object don't have `"` characters around them.

Also, all your `map()` calls should be `forEach()`. `map()` is used to create an array of the results of the function call. But `filterOut()` doesn't return anything, and you don't use the returned value of `map()`.

```js
function filterOut(item) {
  if (Object.values(item).includes(this)) {
    populate(item)
  }
}
```